# Method firm in Java5 with a generic inside another generic

Tags: java, generics, methods, java-5

I have some problem in defining a *Java5* method by using *Generics*.

I experimented that I can define a method as follows:

```
public <R extends Runnable & MyInterface, T> void submit(R runnable, T task);
```

So, `submit` only accept an instance of an object of class `R` that implements the interfaces `Runnable` and `MyInterface`.
Now, suppose I want to do something like follows:

```
public <C extends Callable & MyInterface, T> submit(C<T> callable);
```

where C is a `Callable` that also implements `MyInterface` and has a return value of type `T`. In this case, the IDE reports an error in the firm of the method:

```
required: class
found: type parameter C
where C,T are type-variables
```

What is the right way to define the second `submit` method?

PS: I don't know if the title is the best one. Please, feel free to improve the title once you identify the problem type!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type parameters can't be given other type parameters, e.g. `C<T>` - but they can be bounded by parameterized types. Use the following:

```
public <C extends Callable<T> & MyInterface, T> submit(C callable);
```

Comment: It works... but why I shouldn't specify T in the parameters list?

Comment: See my edit - Basically, `C` is declared once by the method and then used throughout it any number of times. It woudn't make sense to "append" information to it like that.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense! Thank you... I will accept the answer asap! Best regards!